# ga:productPrice via the Analytics Core Reporting API (v3)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Team!

We're currently pushing the product price (ga:productprice) to GA as explained both in the Importing Product Data using the Management API documentation and the [Measuring an Addition or Removal from Cart](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#add-remove-cart) from the Enhanced Ecommerce documentation, but now we find unable to query it, as this metric does not appear in the [Analytics Core Reporting API (v3)documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets). It's that correct?

What is the usefulness of pushing this data to GA if we cannot query it later? It's really kind of strange that you could use ga:ProductBrand, ga:ProductSku... but no the price.

Any clarification on this one would be helpful.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dimension called `ga:productPrice` in Google Analytics. But there are other metrics in GA like `ga:transactionRevenue`, `ga:revenuePerItem`, `ga:itemRevenue` and other transaction and revenue related metrics. Here is the [list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=ecommerce) of Ecommerce related dimension and metrics.

Hope it helps !